# Creating a ul with li in javascript and make li type checkbox with text

Tags: javascript, html-lists, createelement

so I'm trying to make this entire project in JS, and am now trying to translate my UL that's hiding lis that are checkboxes. went through the net but couldn't hack it.

HTML

```
<div class="checkBoxes">
        <span class="recipePicContainer">
            <img class="recipe" src="../images/grasshopper-cocktail.jpg" alt="Cocktail">
            <div>Cocktail</div>
        </span>
        <ul class="recipes">
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 1</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 2</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 3</li>
           <li class="ingredient"><input type="checkbox"> ingredient 4</li>
           <li class="instructions">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

JS

```
var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
    document.$checkboxes.appendChild(ul);

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.className = "ingredients";

        var a = document.createElement("a");
        a.innerHTML = "Subfile " + i;

        li.appendChild(a);
        $recipes.appendChild(li);
    }
```

Comment: _"went through the net but couldn't hack it"_ -- what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy need to define `$checkboxes` first and the append `$recipes` to it, e.g

```
var $recipes = document.createElement("ul");
var $checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('checkBoxes'); 

for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.className = "ingredients";

    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.innerHTML = "Subfile " + i;

    li.appendChild(a);
    $recipes.appendChild(li);

}

$checkboxes[0].appendChild($recipes);
```

You can find working demo of your code on this [Jsbin](https://jsbin.com/puvafo/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Thanx so much @Champ, there are just so many irrelevant examples for something so simple.

Comment: OK, added this in and it created something odd. I will upload on fiddle please help: https://jsfiddle.net/DanDaManEker/f9a7y4rb/

Comment: @DanEker I have tried to solve the problems which I found ... but not sure what you need. Please check https://jsfiddle.net/aLrsupbj/

Comment: Hey again @Champ! So I fixed it up a bit but now my click event isn't working. https://jsfiddle.net/DanDaManEker/aLrsupbj/3/

Comment: you can use jQuery Selector like ```$('.mainContainer .recipePicContainer')``` please check https://jsfiddle.net/tfb6j2ux/1/